# Rollback transaction in hibernate

Tags: hibernate, exception, transactions

I've created Hibernate „create” method:

```
public PK create(T o) {
    try {

        getSession().beginTransaction();
        PK rez = (PK) getSession().save(o);
        getSession().flush();
        getSession().getTransaction().commit();
        return rez;
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        getSession().getTransaction().rollback();
        return null;
    }

}
```

When some exception occurs (for example, unique constraint in DB), then catch block executes. After one error, I cant create another rows… I get exception about old error.  For example, I create user „test”, then I trying add user with same name „test” and I’m getting hibernate error in log file. Then I’m trying to add new unique user, with new username „test2”, but still get old error about „test” user. Where is the problem?

So, real example:

I'm added testuser1@ttt.org, after that, I tryed add this user once more (and gets exception(below))... Now I'm trying to add user "testuser3@ttt.org" but I'm getting this error about testuser1@ttt.org again:

```
[2014-03-23T17:35:17.767+0200] [glassfish 4.0] [WARN] [] [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] [tid: _ThreadID=22 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(5)] [timeMillis: 1395588917767] [levelValue: 900] [[
  SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 23505]]

[2014-03-23T17:35:17.767+0200] [glassfish 4.0] [ERROR] [] [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] [tid: _ThreadID=22 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(5)] [timeMillis: 1395588917767] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "unique_Username"
  Detail: Key (username)=(testuser1@ttt.org ) already exists.]]

[2014-03-23T17:35:17.767+0200] [glassfish 4.0] [SEVERE] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=22 _ThreadName=Thread-4] [timeMillis: 1395588917767] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:129)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:136)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:58)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3067)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3509)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:377)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:369)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:286)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:339)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:52)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1234)
    at org.test.majas.dao.GenericDaoImpl.create(GenericDaoImpl.java:29)
    at org.test.majas.beans.TestBean.addUser(TestBean.java:80)
    .....
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "unique_Username"
  Detail: Key (username)=(testuser1@ttt.org ) already exists.
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2161)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1890)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:255)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:560)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:417)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeUpdate(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:363)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:133)
    ... 63 more]]
```

Thanks.

Comment: The problem is where the stack trace of the exception tells you it is. Why don't you post it?

Comment: So, sorry, added now.

Comment: Any ideas? :( Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, problem was in Session… After each error I must create new Session…